# Show an integral of continuous $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is invertible.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices

> Let
>   $$\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to GL(n,\mathbb{R})$$
>   be a continuous map such that
>   $$\gamma(s+t)=\gamma(s)\gamma(t),\quad\gamma(0)=I,$$
>   for all $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ be a smooth function with compact support such that
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi(t)dt=1.$$
>   How to show that
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi(t)\gamma(t)dt\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})?$$
>   **EDIT:** Thanks to Robert Israel, it is in fact not true...

I was thinking that if this is not true then there exists $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $v\neq 0$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(t)\gamma(t)vdt=0$. But $\gamma(t)v\neq 0$ for all $t$, so we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(t)a_1(t)dt=0,\quad\ldots,\quad\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi(t)a_n(t)dt=0,$$
for some continuous functions $a_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ at least one of them is non-zero. So we can take $t_0$ such that $\psi(t_0)>0$, but then it does not necessarily lead to a contradiction since the integrals are $0$ only on the whole domain $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: What about $\gamma : \theta \mapsto R_\theta$, where $R_\theta$ is the rotation of angle $\theta$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\psi (t)dt$ projects to the Haar measure on $SO_2 (\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(EDITED)

Not true.  Take $n=2$ and $\gamma(t) = \pmatrix{\cos(t) & \sin(t)\cr -\sin(t) & \cos(t)\cr}$.  Take $\psi$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(t)\cos(t)\; dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(t) \sin(t)\; dt = 0$ (i.e. the Fourier transform of $\psi$ is $0$ at $1$ and $-1$).  The indicator function of the interval $[0,2\pi]$ would work, except that it's not smooth.  An appropriate smoothing should work: $\psi(t) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(t+s)\; ds$ where $\phi$ is smooth, nonnegative and compactly supported.

Comment: Does $\psi$ have compact support?

Comment: You can create a good function $\psi$ by using a partition of unity and lifting it to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @D.Thomine Would you like to explain what do you mean more precisely in an answer? I made an edit so that this would answer my question.

Comment: I don't really understand your example. How can you smooth $\psi$ and be sure you still get both integrals $0$? P.S. You probably meant $[0,2\pi]$?

Answer (score 0):

Robert israel's answer explain the problem. I'll just show how to get a smooth function $\psi$, by using [partitions of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity).

Topologically, $SO_2 (\mathbb{R}) \sim \mathbb{S}_1$. The circle is smooth, andthere is an open cover given by $U_1 := \mathbb{S}_1 \setminus \{(1, 0)\}$ and $U_2 := \mathbb{S}_1 \setminus \{(-1, 0)\}$. Hence, we can find two smooth functions $\varphi_1, \varphi_2$ in $\mathcal{C}^\infty (\mathbb{S}_1, [0,1])$ such that:

- $\varphi_1 + \varphi_2 = 1$,
- The support of $\varphi_i$ is in $U_i$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$.

Now, Let $\gamma_1$ be the restriction of $\gamma$ to $I_1 := (-\pi, \pi)$, and $\gamma_2$ the restriction of $\gamma$ to $I_2 := (0, 2 \pi)$. Then each $\gamma_i$ is a diffeomorphism from $I_i$ to $U_i$. Let $2 \pi \psi := 1_{I_1} \cdot \varphi_1 \circ \gamma_1 + 1_{I_2} \cdot \varphi_2 \circ \gamma_2$. Then $\psi$ is smooth, takes its values in $[0,1]$, has compact support, and $\int_\mathbb{R} \psi = 1$. By construction, $\int_\mathbb{R} \psi \cdot \gamma$ is the null matrix.